# Why errorChannel is not getting called in case of MQException from int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter?

Tags: java, spring-integration

Jms outbound-channel-adapter works perfectly fine but I see intermittently this error in the log, however, MQ message still **gets** delivered.

*2019-06-07 10:16:22 [JMSCCThreadPoolWorker-5] INFO  o.s.j.c.CachingConnectionFactory - Encountered a JMSException - resetting the underlying JMS Connection
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ1107: A problem with this connection has occurred.
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:578)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:214)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.consumer(WMQConnection.java:794)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteHconn.callEventHandler(RemoteHconn.java:2903)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteHconn.driveEventsEH(RemoteHconn.java:628)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteDispatchThread.processHconn(RemoteDispatchThread.java:691)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteDispatchThread.run(RemoteDispatchThread.java:233)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.runTask(WorkQueueItem.java:263)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.SimpleWorkQueueItem.runItem(SimpleWorkQueueItem.java:99)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:284)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.runWorkQueueItem(WorkQueueManager.java:312)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$ThreadPoolWorker.run(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:1214)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').*

...This is errorChannel configuration:

```
<int:header-enricher id="errorMsg.HeaderEnricher"
    input-channel="errorChannel"
    output-channel="omniAlertsJmsErrorChannel">
```

...and jms outbound-channel-adapter configured:

```
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter
    id="jmsOutToNE" channel="umpAlertNotificationJMSChannel" 
    destination="senderTopic" 
    jms-template="jmsQueueTemplate" 
    >
```

I am expecting *omniAlertsJmsErrorChannel* to receive the *MessageHandlingException* which is not happening from *jmsOutToNE* adapter. All other channel/flow errors are being routed to *omniAlertsJmsErrorChannel*.

Also, wondering if there jms outbound-channel-adapter is retrying internally when *com.ibm.mq.MQException* happens and it gets successful in the subsequent try?

Answer (score 0):

The `errorChannel` is out of use in any `MessageHandler`. Their exception are just thrown to the caller. To handle those exception you need to consider adding a `request-handler-advice-chain` with the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`. Or if we talk about a *retry*, you also can add to that chain a `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice`.

See more info in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#message-handler-advice-chain).

Not sure though why your message is still delivered to the MQ. There is no any retry out-of-the-box in the `<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter`. It might a behavior of the MQ Connection Factory adapter in the IBM library.

Comment: "Their exception are just thrown to the caller. " Any reason why errorChannel( omniAlertsJmsErrorChannel) is getting called in case of int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter however, it is getting called from all other components(adapters) in the flow.

Comment: It depends of the flow: how you produce messages. If they come from the Inbound Channel Adapter or QueueChannel (poller) or from Message-Driven Channel Adapter, then thrown exception is going to they `errorChannel`. If you send message yourself, then exception is thrown to your caller.

Comment: Message is flowing through service-activator
 <int:service-activator id="statusUpdate"
  input-channel="statusUpdateChannel"
  output-channel="umpAlertNotificationJMSChannel"
  ref="omniAlertsStatusUpdater" method="updateStatus" />

 >>> return statement in service-activator is :
  return (MessageBuilder.withPayload(processorPayload.getDeliveryMessage())
    .setHeader("processorPayload", processorPayload)
    .setHeader("ConsumerCode", processorPayload.getDeliveryContactType().getDeliveryChannel()).build());

>>> so it should send error to errorChannel. where am I wrong?

Comment: That's not a fact yet. Someone is sending messages to that `statusUpdateChannel`. isn't it? So, according your brief description an exception is thrown there. Please, read more about error handling in the Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#namespace-errorhandler. To make it clear for us and let us to give you an explanation, we need to see the whole flow: from the point where messages are emitted in first place until this `<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter`. Only that way we may see why an exception is not thrown to the `errorChannel` you want.